# How can I click button behind the mask layer?

Tags: ios, button, calayer, mask, cashapelayer

I've one fooView inside of my self.view, fooView has a layer mask which is hiding some part fooView alo I have button behind of that hided part. So I'm seeing button but can't click it because of mask layer is in front of it.
I've added layer like this..
I wanted to click mesajlar button in the picture..

[image]

```
CAShapeLayer *shape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shape.path = pathRef;

shape.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
shape.frame = self.view.frame;
[shape setFillColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[self.viewBottomAbiInfo.layer setMask:shape];
```

I've searched and found pointInside method but its for only views..

```
pointInside:<#(CGPoint)#> withEvent:<#(UIEvent *)#>
```

Any advice would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem with bringing all views and buttons in front of the hiding mask.. like code below,

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnMessages];
```

It's not the best answer but saved the day this time..